# algorithm for byte addressing in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have got an int array of "int word[10000]". i need a way such that 4 consecutive numbers corresponds to 1 element of an array. (byte addressing)

for example:

```
0, 1 , 2 , 3 refers to word[0]
4, 5 , 6 , 7 refers to word[1]
8 , 9 , 10 , 11 refers to word[2]
.....
396, 397, 398, 399 refers to word[100]
```

without using hash map or any other data structure.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `index/4`?

Comment: Like a simple integer division? `0/4=1/4=2/4=3/4=0` and `4/4=5/4=6/4=7/4=1`,

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve by this "byte addressing"? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude making a memory simulator in which i am storing 32 bit integer and i want to be able to store each byte separately in the word.

Comment: Then you probably want to use *pointers* instead of simple division. Like e.g. `uint8_t* p = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(word);` and then e.g. `p[0]` to get the first byte. It should not break strict aliasing since there are exceptions to allow it through pointers to `char`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the aim is not to make a separate pointer for each byte because i want to make very big memory blocks. 
can i just use like: floor(byte address / 4)

Comment: With a single `char` pointer to the whole `word` array, indexes `0`, `1`, `2` and `3` corresponds to `word[0]`. Indexes `4`, `5`, `6` and `7` corresponds to `word[1]`. Etc. Only one pointer needed. You should probably [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read up on pointers an arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
unsigned char *bytes=static_cast<unsigned char*>(word);
unsigned char first=bytes[0];
unsigned char second=bytes[1];
```

`bytes` will index through `word` as an array of `10000*sizeof(int)` bytes though it appears you already know your platform has `sizeof(int)==4`.

NB 1: There's a rule that `sizeof(unsigned char)==1`. The best way to access bytes is usually through `unsigned char`.

NB 2: Whether your platform is big or little-endian will determine if `bytes[0]` is the least or most significant byte of the first element (and so on).